# Twitter API returning client-not-enrolled error

Tags: curl, twitter, bearer-token

I'm trying to consult data from Twitter API, but is returning this error:

```json
{
    "client_id": "xxxxxx",
    "detail": "When authenticating requests to the Twitter API v2 endpoints, you must use keys and tokens from a Twitter developer App that is attached to a Project. You can create a project via the developer portal.",
    "registration_url": "https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/projects/overview",
    "title": "Client Forbidden",
    "required_enrollment": "Appropriate Level of API Access",
    "reason": "client-not-enrolled",
    "type": "https://api.twitter.com/2/problems/client-forbidden"
}
```

The current project that I'm using is also attached to Twitter API v2 endpoints:

[image: image of developer portal]

Is it a problem of Twitter or just am I making something wrong?
This is my curl call also:

```
curl --location 'https://api.twitter.com/2/users/by/username/xxxxx' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxx' \
--header 'Cookie: guest_id=xxxxx'
```

Also if I put wrong credentials return unauthorized error, so I don't think is a bearer token problem.

Comment: The "Free" access tier can only access a very limited set of V2 (or any) Twitter APIs. "Users by username" isn't one of those.